# Open (IN...) command failing possibly due to problems with naming

Tags: perl, praat

New to Perl and quite new to coding in general so I apologise if this is formatted terribly and an easy question! Trying simply to input somebody's elses code as a step in a larger project involving PRAAT. The code is designed to distinguish beats in speech rhythm, I've followed their nomenclature in file naming (on line 2) but the code won't move past line 13. Could anyone tell me why? Is it trying to open a directory called "intensities"? Additionally, is there anywhere else I may have to change the code, it is quite possibly reasonably old! Thank you very much!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
scalar(@ARGV) == 1 or scalar(@ARGV) == 2 or die "Usage: getBeatsOneShot.pl someSoundFile <threshold>";
$stem = shift;

# Parameters to fiddle with
if (scalar(@ARGV) == 0) {
  $threshold = 0.2;
} else {
  $threshold = shift;
  print "Threshold is $threshold\n";
}

open(IN, "intensities/$stem.intensity") or die "badly";
open(OUT, ">beats/$stem.beats")  or die "eek";

# File type = "ooTextFile short"
$_ = <IN>; print OUT $_;

# replace "Intensity" with "TextGrid"
$_ = <IN>; print OUT "\"TextGrid\"\n\n";

# skip a line
$_ = <IN>;

chomp($xmin = <IN>);
chomp($xmax = <IN>);
chomp($nx = <IN>);  $nx = 0; #(just suprress a arning here)
chomp($dx = <IN>);
chomp($x1 = <IN>);

# Read in intensity contour into @e (envelope)
@e = ();
while($_ = <IN>) { chomp; last unless $_ eq "1";}
push @e, $_;

while($_ = <IN>) {
  chomp($_);
  push @e, $_;
}


# (1) Find max and min
$max = 0; $min = 1000000;
foreach $ival (@e) {
  if($ival > $max) {
    $max = $ival;
  }
  if($ival < $min) {
    $min = $ival;
  }
}

# (2) look for beats
@beats = ();

print "Thresh: $threshold\n";
```

Comment: Instead of "eek" and "badly", `die $!` so you know what went wrong.

Comment: `intensities` and `beats` directories should exist in the current directory before you run the script.

Comment: @choroba It is very likely that you nailed the problem. There is certainly nothing else that can cause the program to crash. I would write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

[open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open) doesn't create the path to the file. Directories `intensities/` and `beats/` therefore must exist in the current working directory before the script is run.

When [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open) fails, it sets [$!](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$OS_ERROR) to the reason of the failure. Instead of `eek` or `badly`, use `die $!` so Perl can tell you what went wrong.

Moreover, you should turn [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) and [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) on. They prevent many common mistakes. As a newbie, you might like to enable [diagnostics](http://p3rl.org/diagnostics), too, to get detailed explanations of all the errors and warnings.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a suspicion the problem was along these lines but it feels good to have it confirmed! I will enable the other beginner buffers too that sounds like a great idea!